# Drawback in using too many keywords

Tags: seo, keyword, meta

A client lists over 20 keywords for its website, is there any drawback if putting all into the <meta keywords=""> on only one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FACT: Meta keywords have no effect on SEO.

Also, there is no official requirement regarding the length of a 'keyword' tag, but generally you'll find people listing it all across the internet anywhere from 100 to 255 characters.

Make sure to use the words that match the content of your client's website. And yes, don't worry about anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Meta keywords don't have an impact on SEO anymore. Instead, you should focus on content and getting backlinks to appropriate pages.